# Pass variable from LWC to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, controller

Not sure of the syntax to pass parameters from lwc javascript to my apex controller.

js

```
import createCustomer from '@salesforce/apex/HttpCallout.createStripeCustomer';
export default class showProducts extends LightningElement {

    name;
    email;

    handleSave() {
            createCustomer(***what do I put here***)
            .then(result => {
                console.log('result-------', result);
                const response = JSON.parse(result);
                this.customerId = response.id;
                

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('this.createError' + error);
                
            });
    }
```

controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createStripeCustomer(***AND what do I put here***) {
    
    some code
.....
```

I have hard-coded the parameters in the controller, so the call works. I'm now trying to pass live data from the lwc and get that working. I've only been able to find @wire examples which this is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was more simple than I thought. . .

two lines:
js
createCustomer({name: 'Skip', email: 'skip@gmail.com'})

controller
public static String createStripeCustomer(String name, String email) {